# How to do logical partitioning in SGE?

Tags: sungridengine

I am using GE2011.11. Previously, I was using Torque/Maui. In Maui, there is a concept of partition with the help of which we can logically divide the cluster. A node can't belong to more than one partition.

In GE, I am thinking of host groups to achieve this but a node(host) can belong to more than one host group this is what is undesirable. Any idea, how can we achieve partitioning with host groups?

In GE, there is a feature called multi-clustering. Can we use this feature to implement partitioning? Any idea, how do we use this?

Answer (score 0):

With SGE you can modify the host groups manually so that a host(node) only exists in a single host group.  You can then create queues that only use a single host group.  The users would then submit jobs to the specific queues(which themselves can be limited by users) to access specific host groups.  This would effectively divide your grid.

The basic things to look out for when performing this setup relates to the all.q queue and the @allhosts hosts group.  If you remove all hosts from the @allhosts group you should be okay to do this.

Let me know if you have further questions, I would be happy to help as I have been administering an SGE cluster for years now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the administrator defines the membership of hostgroups  just define the groups so as not to overlap.  If you want to control which users can run on which partition you can do this  by defining grid engine acls/usersets for each group of users and using the enhanced queue configuration syntax to associate a different list with each hostgroup in the queue definitions.

```
user_lists chemists,[@physicshosts=physicists],[@biologyhosts=biologists]
```

If what you are trying to do is ensure a given job runs on one set of hosts or the other but not a mixture then you need to define multiple identical parallel environments and use a similar trick to associate each PE with a different hostgroup.

```
pe_list mpich-A,[@switchb=mpich-B],[@switchc=mpich-C]
```

Users then request a wildcard PE when submitting their job:

```
#$ -pe mpich-* 8
```